# Couchbase query not returning document unless I `USE KEYS`

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++

I've got a document that should be returned by a query isn't. Here's what I know.

**Query 1 - Which SHOULD return the document**
`select * from bucketName where field="value"`

**Returns**
 `[]`

**Query 2 - Which DOES return the document** 
`select * from bucketName use keys 'documentID' where field="value"`

**Returns**
`[<Document>]`

**Query 3 - Fails with `scan_consistency=request_plus`**
`select * from bucketName where field="Value"`

**Returns**
`Failed to access view keyspace bucket_keyspace or view index missing`

**Query 4 - List keyspaces**
`SELECT * FROM system:keyspaces;`

**Returns**

```
[
  {
    "keyspaces": {
      "datastore_id": "http://127.0.0.1:8091",
      "id": "bucket_keyspace",
      "name": "bucket_keyspace",
      "namespace_id": "default"
    }
  }
]
```

I think for some reason the index for the bucket isn't being updated? But I can't see any builds in progess etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm super stumped

Comment: Which version are you using? What platform are you running on? About how many documents are there in your bucket? It is possible that there's a problem with the primary index, you could try dropping and recreating it. Also, your Query 4 says that the bucket's name is "bucket_keyspace", but your query refers to "bucketName". What is the actual bucket name and query you are using?

Comment: Can you try to recreate the index/view? btw, what are the indexes you have in your database? If you don't have a primary index or a GSI that will cover this query, it won't return anything

Comment: Still not sure what the error was but I dropped & recreated the GSI and another relevant index and it seems to be fixed now.
Thanks for the help anyways!